# Binding input field to model in MVC5 using bootstrap display formatting

Tags: c#-4.0, binding, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-input, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating an MVC 5 site using bootstrap 3.0.0. I'm having difficulty binding the model to an input field. I simply don't know the syntax for doing this.

The following code works functionally, but I lose bootstrap's styling.

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</div>
```

On the other hand, this block of code looks great, but I can't get the binding to work.
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name here..."/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

So I need some assistance either getting the top block or bottom block to work. Either the right syntax to make it work functionally, or a slick method of attaching to the correct CSS in bootstrap to make it look attractive.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were very close.
In order to confirm right syntax, always reference to [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your name here..." })
            <span class="input-group-addon">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

There is a simpler way if you don't want to worry about all the right html structure and css classes required by Bootstrap being applied: [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/)

With that you'd write something like this:

```
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form().Type(FormType.Horizontal)))
{
    @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.Name).Placeholder("Enter your name here...")
    @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton())
}
```

or something like this if you want it to render with prepends and appends:

```
@using (Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form()))
{
    @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        .Placeholder("Enter your name here...")
        .Prepend(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Name))
        .Append(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Name)))
    @Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton()
}
```

using this library for Bootstrap 3 is not free, but you might find it cheaper than the time you spend figuring out syntax required by Bootstrap on your own. There is also a Trial version if you want to try it out first.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of TwitterBootstrapMVC

Comment: Thank you. This helps greatly. I'm trying out your library now and I'm sure it will make my upcoming project a lot easier!